# how to connect java swing application to mariadb DB using GSSAPI?

Tags: java, authentication, mariadb, gssapi

I have an application, which needs to connect to MariaDB DB version 10.1 using GSSAPI.
I have enabled the GSSAPI plugin on the database side, and have created a user via -

```
    create user 'user'@'%' IDENTIFIED via 'gssapi' as 'user';
```

Now, i am trying to connect from the application as -

```
        Class.forName("org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3305/schema?user='user'&gssapi-principal-name='user@localhost'");

        stmt = con.createStatement();
```

I am getting the exception when i am trying to get the connection from DB -

```
java.sql.SQLInvalidAuthorizationSpecException: GSS-API authentication exception
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.ExceptionMapper.get(ExceptionMapper.java:121)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.ExceptionMapper.throwException(ExceptionMapper.java:69)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:110)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)


Caused by: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Unable to obtain Principal Name for authentication 
at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.promptForName(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.attemptAuthentication(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.login(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(Unknown Source)
at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(Unknown Source)
at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(Unknown Source)
at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(Unknown Source)
at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(Unknown Source)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.packet.send.SendGssApiAuthPacket.send(SendGssApiAuthPacket.java:115)
... 46 more
```

Any idea how to resolve it?

Comment: have a look at https://github.com/MariaDB/mariadb-connector-j/blob/master/documentation/plugin/GSSAPI.creole

Comment: I tried this one, but still the same issue!